# RavenDB DateTime error after updating to 2.5.5.2700

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ravendb

After updating to latest RavenDB i get this error:

> [InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Index_Auto_2fDocuments_2fByCreationDateTimeAndPublishTimeSortByCreationDateTimePublishTime' to type 'Raven.Database.Linq.AbstractViewGenerator'.]
>      Raven.Database.Linq.DynamicViewCompiler.GenerateInstance() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Linq\DynamicViewCompiler.cs:598
>      Raven.Database.Storage.IndexDefinitionStorage.AddAndCompileIndex(IndexDefinition indexDefinition) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Storage\IndexDefinitionStorage.cs:233
>      Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.PutIndex(String name, IndexDefinition definition) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\DocumentDatabase.cs:1207
>      Raven.Database.Queries.DynamicQueryRunner.CreateAutoIndex(String permanentIndexName, Func`1 createDefinition) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Queries\DynamicQueryRunner.cs:170
>      Raven.Database.Queries.DynamicQueryRunner.GetAppropriateIndexToQuery(String entityName, IndexQuery query, DynamicQueryMapping map) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Queries\DynamicQueryRunner.cs:158
>      Raven.Database.Queries.DynamicQueryRunner.ExecuteDynamicQuery(String entityName, IndexQuery query) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Queries\DynamicQueryRunner.cs:32
>      Raven.Client.Embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseCommands.Query(String index, IndexQuery query, String[] includes, Boolean metadataOnly, Boolean indexEntriesOnly) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Embedded\EmbeddedDatabaseCommands.cs:481
>      Raven.Client.Document.AbstractDocumentQuery`2.ExecuteActualQuery() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\AbstractDocumentQuery.cs:664
>      Raven.Client.Document.AbstractDocumentQuery`2.get_QueryResult() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\AbstractDocumentQuery.cs:633
>      Raven.Client.Linq.RavenQueryProviderProcessor`1.ExecuteQuery() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Linq\RavenQueryProviderProcessor.cs:1499
>      Raven.Client.Linq.RavenQueryInspector`1.GetEnumerator() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Linq\RavenQueryInspector.cs:105
>      System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +446
>      System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +80
>      Kernel.DocumentRavenProvider.GetDocuments(Int32 count) in c:\Dev\Repos\Git\Writer\Kernel\DocumentRavenProvider.cs:85
>      Kernel.DocumentManager.GetDocuments(Int32 count) in c:\Dev\Repos\Git\Writer\Kernel\DocumentManager.cs:46
>      Blog.Controllers.DocumentController.Index() in c:\Dev\Repos\Git\Writer\Blog\Controllers\DocumentController.cs:18
>      lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +79
>      System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +261
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +39
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass42.b*_41() +34
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass39.b*_33() +124
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass4f.b*_49() +838923
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass37.b*_36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +15
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass2a.b*_20() +33
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass25.b*_22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +839508
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass1d.b*_18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +65
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +51
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass8.b*_3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +51
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288

When executing this query

```
documents = session.Query<Model.Document>().Where(d => d.PublishTime <= DateTime.Now)
.OrderByDescending(document=>document.CreationDateTime).Take(count)
```

I am running with a embedded database, and I have tried to

1. remove database and restart asp.net application. ***Same error***.
2. add something to database, then restart and load asp.net application. ***Same error***.

Before update, erverything worked fine. I have alot of unit tests where I test against an inmemory Raven database. Here the save and retrieval work fine, so maybe it has something to do with the json being parsed?

I have this controller that calls the underlying RavenDB save logic:

```
// POST api/document
        public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Model.Document> Post([FromBody]Model.Document document)
        {
            var savedDocument = await _documentManager.Save(document);

            var hubConnection = new Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Hubs.HubConnection(BaseSiteUrl);
            var hub = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("DocumentHub");
            hubConnection.Start().Wait();
            hub.Invoke("NewArticle", savedDocument.Id).Wait();

            return document;
        }
```

My Model looks like this

```
    public class Document
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Headline { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationDateTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime PublishTime { get; set; }
        public HashSet<string> Tags { get; private set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        [Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]
        public Model.Category Category { get; private set; }

        public Document()
        {
            CreationDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            Tags = new HashSet<string>();
        }

        public Document(string headline, string text, DateTime creationTime, DateTime publishTime)
        {
            Headline = headline;
            Text = text;
            CreationDateTime = creationTime;
            PublishTime = publishTime;
            Tags = new HashSet<string>();
        }

        public string GetCategoryName()
        {
            string name = String.Empty;

            if (this.Category != null)
            {
                name = this.Category.Name;
            }

            return name;
        }

        public void SetCategory(Model.Category category)
        {
            if (category != null)
            {
                this.Category = category;
                this.CategoryId = category.Id;
            }
        }

        public string GetTeaser()
        {
            string teaser = Text;
            if (Text.Count() > 250)
                teaser = Text.Substring(0, 250) + " ...";

            return teaser;
        }

        public string GetCommaSeperatedTagsString()
        {
            var tags = new StringBuilder();

            int i = 0;
            foreach (string tag in Tags)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tag))
                {
                    tags.Append(tag);

                    if (i < Tags.Count - 1)
                    {
                        tags.Append(",");
                    }
                }
                i++;

            }

            return tags.ToString();
        }

        public string GetSpaceSeperatedTagsString()
        {
            var tags = new StringBuilder();

            int i = 0;
            foreach (string tag in Tags)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tag))
                {
                    tags.Append(tag);

                    if (i < Tags.Count - 1)
                    {
                        tags.Append(" ");
                    }
                }
                i++;

            }

            return tags.ToString();
        }

        public void AddTagsString(string tagsString)
        {
            string[] tagsSplitted = tagsString.Split(',');

            foreach (var tag in tagsSplitted)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tag))
                {
                    Tags.Add(tag);
                }
            }
        }

        public string GetTimeString()
        {
            System.TimeSpan span = DateTime.Now.Subtract(this.CreationDateTime);
            string time = "lige udgivet";

            if (span.Days > 0)
            {
                if (span.Days > 1)
                    time = span.Days + " dage siden";
                else
                    time = "en dag siden";
            }

            else if (span.Hours > 0)
            {
                if (span.Hours > 1)
                    time = span.Hours + " timer siden";
                else
                    time = "en time siden";
            }

            else if (span.Minutes > 0)
            {
                if (span.Minutes > 1)
                    time = span.Minutes + " minutter siden.";
                else
                    time = "et minut siden.";
            }

            else if (span.Seconds > 0)
            {
                time = "lige udgivet";
            }
            else if (span.Milliseconds > 0)
            {
                time = "lige udgivet";
            }

            return time;
        }
    }

public class Category
            {
                public string Name { get; set; }
                public int Id { get; set; }
            }
```

However, if I break in the controller method above, the json is transformed just fine. No errors here.

Has RavenDB changed the way DateTime is handled? Does anyone know to a solution, or an article that will point me in the right direction.

**Update**
I can see this only happens when I try to query the database and get documents. This is tested on a empty database, and a database with documents. I can see that the save method work just fine.

Comment: What version are you updating *from*?  Also, see http://ravendb.net/kb/61/working-with-date-and-time-in-ravendb

Comment: I updated via Nuget from version 2.5.2666. In that version everything worked fine. I have not updated my codebase, just updated RavenDB, recompiled codebase and restarted my IIS.

Comment: There have certainly been no breaking changes about datetimes between 2666 and 2700.  But perhaps there's something in the indexing.  Try deleting the auto index and let it rebuild itself.  I assume the problem doesn't happen when you start with a clean empty database, right?

Comment: The error happens when I use a clean and empty database.

Comment: Interesting...  Can you edit your question and show what your `Model.Document` class looks like?  A sample of the JSON from Raven management studio would also be useful.  And you said this is embedded, right?

Comment: I tried to reproduce it and I don't see the error you have.  Please review my unit test [here](https://gist.github.com/mj1856/6488023) and let me know if you're doing something substantially different.

Comment: I will try to reproduce tomorrow and show the code.

Comment: I cannot seem to reproduce this within a console. This is killing me. I have updated my question with my Document class.

Comment: If I remove the OrderByDescending, everything works fine. This is on an empty database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed by uninstalling Raven.Embedded from nuget, and reinstalling.

Comment: I am getting the exact same error in the in-memory database but uninstalling did not work for me. I do notice that by evaluating the query with .List() before calling the .Where seems to work. I have not confirm that this is the case in the web instance.